# (web) Light weight teleop interface

Tags: ros, android-teleop

[image: Rosanswers logo]

How can I get the source code for the Turtlebot Android App? I'd like to create a generalized html5 based application for controlling ROS robots via a teleop interface.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/195530/(web)-light-weight-teleop-interface/) by [DrBot](https://answers.ros.org/users/765/drbot/) on ROS Answers with karma: 147 on 2014-10-21

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2014-10-21**:
The turtlebot android apps are written in Java. There isn't much there that will be portable to html5.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I would suggest that you look at [Robot Web Tools](http://robotwebtools.org/) for a way to make modern web interfaces.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2014-10-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1